# Is it possible to rearrange a mobile web UI given a link?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile-phones, titanium

Given a link:

http://m.llmtrafik.gov.my/TrafficList.aspx

It works well if I browse it on Mobile Safari.

However, I'm thinking of designing a free application by transforming the mobile page(3rd party) into an application by:

- removing top panel which contains image button
- remove the footer which contains copyright information

Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "remove the footer which contains copyright information" That'd be a copyright violation and illegal in (at least) most western nations. Wouldn't surprise me if Malaysia got pissed too.

Comment: It sucks... I will email to the department to get their approval before i really remove the copyright statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `'media=screen'` to target iPhone and Android devices for CSS. Here's a [decent link](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/optimizing-websites-iphone-and-android/) on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. What if I am a third party user, intended to customize the webpage into my own style? I don't have access to its CSS and html file?

Comment: @Sam: No, if it's not your website then you won't be able to make changes like this.